# How to get a variable to equal one of the strings within a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have been dabbling in Python for a bit and I have come across a problem that I can't seem to solve. I want to have a variable equal one of the strings within a list (the list is passed to the function that the variable is in). I do not want to pin point the exact variable eg. var[0] , but I want Python to search the list for a matching string.

```
def order_in(produce2):
    print 'INFO ON INCOMING ORDER'
    produce_name = raw_input("Name of Produce: ")
    produce_stock = raw_input("Number of %s: " % produce_name)
    if produce_name == # Here is where I need help
        print "Added %s to %s" % (produce_stock, produce_name)

produce2 = ['basil', 'green_beans', 'carrots_bunch']
```

I want something that will result in the code searching through produce2 for a string match. Maybe something to do with any(). I have tried produce2[:], but I think that only is useful if one wants the variable to include all produce2.

I an still quite new to programming and any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if produce_name in produce2`?

Comment: make `produce2` a set and use `in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if produce_name in produce2:
    print "Added %s to %s" % (produce_stock, produce_name)
```

is what you are looking for

Comment: Beat me by a second! :P

Comment: @idjaw, that's why he has 38.4k :)

Comment: actually by `6` seconds

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to do this:

`if produce_name in produce2:`